# How to trigger a function on a old Activity when returning from a newer activity?

Tags: java, android

i am wanting to Trigger a event on the old activity when returning back from the newer activity.

so when i hit the Done button and im using `Finish();` to return back to the old  Activity this works but i need to update the ui on the old activity.
do i set up for a `OnActivityResultListener`? and handle it that way? im not exactly sure how to set that up but im sure there is plenty of info on that else were.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use below method to start your activity

```
static final int YOUR_REQUEST_CODE = 1;  // The request code
startActivityForResult(yourIntent, YOUR_REQUEST_CODE);
```

And then, in the **OLD** activity, override below method:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // Check which request we're responding to
    if (requestCode == YOUR_REQUEST_CODE) {
        // Make sure the request was successful
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            // Do something with here.
        }
    }
}
```

More details can be found at [Android Developer Official Guide](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result#java)