# onActivityResult Method call onbutton click

Tags: android

[image]please write the answer 
how to call onActivityResult of fragment on button click

[image]

```
 Button button=view.findViewById(R.id.bbbtttnnn);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent=new Intent();
                intent.putExtra("name","charan");
                startActivityForResult(intent,45);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Just a sidenote: Try as much as possible to always give your IDs meaningful/relevant names. I learnt the hard way when I had to go back to a codebase I wrote two years earlier. It also helps other people that might want to work on your code.

Comment: Can you tell me exactly what/why you want to do? May be we can help with other ways as your code doesn't seems that you required like this.

Comment: Dont know why question got so many ups? just google a bit yourself. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10407159/how-to-manage-startactivityforresult-on-android. You clearly don't understand how ActivityForResult works. So I suggest you start reading about it asap.

Comment: @VygintasB Read carefully. Its different question than others.

Comment: @PratikButani The answer is same. In short you can't call onActivityResult yourself. It is called then activity you open returns result.

Comment: Check the answer here: [How to trigger a function on a old Activity when returning from a newer activity?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54058428/8034839)

Comment: @VygintasB before understanding the question how you mention duplicate ?

Comment: @Prabhdeep I understand everything clearly. Just follow up answer. I'm 110% sure It's solution. And I ask you question. Why ask question before doing research yourself?

Comment: @VygintasB i have already used this link

Comment: @VygintasB  please remove duplicate word

Comment: @VygintasB i clearly mention that how to call fragment onActivityResult only not call Activity method

Comment: @Prabhdeep It does not matter if it's in activity or fragment. Execution is still same....

Comment: @VygintasB please check practically its not working same

Comment: @Prabhdeep Sorry, but I'm done with you. I'm trying to help you, but you keep your position same. Please read about `startActivityForResult` first. Error in your logcat is useless, because you not even starting activity right. There is answers bellow which point it out.

Comment: i m telling you answer but  please  remove duplicate if the  answer  same with your link  you can give negative vote okk

Comment: Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(),
                    XYZActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("name","prabh");
            startActivityForResult(intent , 45);

use like this

Comment: i have already used this  but activty reopen its not solution and this logic for call activity method not for fragment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define constant

```
public static final int REQUEST_CODE = 1;
```

Use intent

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Activity.this,
                    XYZActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent , REQUEST_CODE);
```

Now use onActivityResult to retrieve the result

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        try {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

            if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE  && resultCode  == RESULT_OK) {

                String requiredValue = data.getStringExtra("key");
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Toast.makeText(Activity.this, ex.toString(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }
```

In next screen use this code to set result

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
intent.putExtra("key", value);
setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
finish();
```

Comment: but i used fragment

Comment: Then what issue you are facing ?

Comment: appclication crashed on button click

Comment: Can you show error log

Comment: @RahulArora , The answer you have given will simply open the activity , which he does not want to ,

Comment: please check this images